# How do I get the URL of a SPA to update when using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm working on an app with the following flow (Using React, and react-router)
 1. User goes to homepage and types in a city name into a serachbar then clicks a button. (at this point, the URL should be localhost:8080/
 2. On click of the button, a neighborhoods component will mount giving you a list of neighborhoods in that specific city you typed in. (at this point, the URL should be localhost:8080/city/neighborhoods.
3. So now that we see a list of neighborhoods, you can click on a neighborhood and get details about it, like population and size etc. (at this point, the URL should be localhost:8080/city/neighborhood/detail.

Right now, I'm using react-router for the routes. This is the code:

```
`ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="city" component={City}>
          <Route path="/neighborhood" component={Neighborhood} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider`
```

Since the main component being called is App, I've also given App.js {this.props.children}.

On my local machine, none of the clicks are changing the URL but if i type in localhost:8080/city/neighborhood/detail, nothing happens, it just stays the same. No error.

How do I get the URL to change automatically when the user clicks different buttons that render different components?

Comment: There's no reason to have a `Router` component within another `Router` component. You can add the history prop to the inner `Router` and remove the outer `Router`. Also how are you calling your routes? Say when someone clicks on the button ?

Comment: @realseanp maybe the person just made a typo. Remove the "r" from the inner one and it should be fine.

Comment: So, I updated the typo. As for how I'm calling the routes: `<Link to="city">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Link>`

The problem I'm now having is that the URL updates like it's supposed to on click of the button, BUT the button has now lost all functionality and is not rendering the City component as it should. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your component that contains the button? I need more context.

Answer (score -1):

You do not reach that URL because you have not defined it in your route, change your route to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={history}>
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="city" component={City}>
           <Route path="neighborhood" component={Neighborhood}>
            <Route path="detail" component={detail}>
           </Route>
         </Route>
     </Route>
  </Router>
 </Provider>
)
```

if you are not using a "detail" component and it is something like a modal just use javascript to open the modal.
if you are using Neighborhood component for detail and you are just changing the URL and updating the component please follow below instruction:
your route should be like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={history}>
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="city" component={City}>
           <Route path="neighborhood" component={Neighborhood}>
             <Route path="(:variable)" component={Neighborhood}>//variable is a parameter, which will be used in the component to get the last part of URL it helps you to create pages other than "detail" with no need to more child routes
           </Route>
         </Route>
     </Route>
  </Router>
 </Provider>
)
```

in Neighborhood component:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  var {variable} = this.params
  if(variable === "detail"){
    //do something. probably change a state to change a part of your view in order to show city detail.
  }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: You dont want to use window.location.href = ... React router has built in methods/components to handle changing routes.

Comment: @realseanp I know but the questionnaire has provided no more information about the components structure and also window.location.href is a pure javascript solution. So that, why not using that?

Comment: React router stores some internal state including the current location. In order for React Router to store/update that state properly you would need to use the built in methods. Using window.location.href would break things.

Comment: @realseanp I agree, but I'm just saying that in this case if using Link is breaking the code, using window.location.href = ... would solve the issue and yes we should consider its effects on React-Router state. I updated my answer and removed that part.